# ErrorNo backend found in registry error while using TensorFlow.js in Node.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, model, mobilenet

I'm trying to use TensorFlow.js in Node.js to classify an image using MobileNet. However, I'm getting the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: No backend found in registry.`

I understand that this error is related to the lack of a registered backend, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Here's the code that I'm using:

Here is the full error

```
 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No backend found in registry.     at w.getSortedBackends (engine.js:267:19)     at w.initializeBackendsAndReturnBest (engine.js:276:37)     at get backend [as backend] (engine.js:108:46)     at w.makeTensor (engine.js:612:35)     at a (tensor_ops_util.js:57:12)     at n (tensor.js:49:12)     at Module.d (io_utils.js:214:25)     at d.loadSync (graph_model.js:141:35)     at graph_model.js:116:54     at async u (graph_model.js:417:5)
```

What should I do to fix this error. Thank you in advance. Any guidance is much appreciated.

I also tried using the tf cdn, but I kept getting the same error. It was stating that I have no registered backend.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be occurring due to version mismatch.

Commonly occurring amongst users, it is advised to use these versions during the time of importing tfjs.

```
<!-- Load TensorFlow.js. This is required to use MobileNet. -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.1"> </script>
<!-- Load the MobileNet model. -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/mobilenet@1.0.0"> </script>
```

If you're not using script tags, you can do it via the Node Package Manager in the following way:

```
// Note: you do not need to import @tensorflow/tfjs here.

const mobilenet = require('@tensorflow-models/mobilenet');

const img = document.getElementById('img');

// Load the model.
const model = await mobilenet.load();

// Classify the image.
const predictions = await model.classify(img);

console.log('Predictions: ');
console.log(predictions);
```

View full reference guide [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/mobilenet).